# Segmentation error comes in english to morsecode and i dont know why

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, char

Can someone tell me why  this code is not working anymore? IT was working perfectly fine yesterday now its giving me segmentation fault(core dump)
(This is just filler text because i dont know what to explain anymore, i wrote this code some days ago and it was working perfectly however now its giving me a segmentation error core dump and i dont know the cause to that sadly, so please if anyone could help me and guide me so i can fix this error i would be greateful)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int Strlen(char *s1)
 /*returns the length of string in number of characters...*/
{
int length=0;
    while(*s1!='\0')
    {
        *s1++;
        length++;
     }
return length;
}

int main()
{
int option=0, length=0;
cout<<"     \\\\WELCOME TO THE MORSE CONVERTER//"<<endl;

cout<<"Select which type of conversion you want to do:"<<endl;
cout<<"1) Sentence to Morse Code"<<endl;
cout<<"2) Morse Code to Sentence"<<endl;
cin>>option;
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
        char arr[1000];
        char* ptr;
        cout<<"Write your sentence to convert in Morse Code\n";
            cin.ignore();                   //USED TO REFRESH THE CIN BUFFER (WITHOUT THIS THE GETLINE FUNCTION WILL NOT TAKE INPUT)
        cin.getline(ptr,1000);              //TAKING SENTENCE INPUT INTO THE CHARACTER ARRAY
        cout<<"Your sentence is:\n"<<ptr<<endl;
        
        length=Strlen(ptr);             //TELLS US THE LENGTH OF THE ARRAY
        for(int i=0; *(arr+i)<=length; i++)         //WE TAKE i<=length BECAUSE THE STRLEN FUNCTION DOESNT COUNT \0
        {
            if(*(arr+i)=='A'||*(arr+i)=='a')
            cout<<".-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='B'||*(arr+i)=='b')
            cout<<"-...";
            if(*(arr+i)=='C'||*(arr+i)=='c')
            cout<<"-.-.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='D'||*(arr+i)=='d')
            cout<<"-..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='E'||*(arr+i)=='e')
            cout<<".";
            if(*(arr+i)=='F'||*(arr+i)=='f')
            cout<<"..-.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='G'||*(arr+i)=='g')
            cout<<"--.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='H'||*(arr+i)=='h')
            cout<<"....";
            if(*(arr+i)=='I'||*(arr+i)=='i')
            cout<<"..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='J'||*(arr+i)=='j')
            cout<<".---";
            if(*(arr+i)=='K'||*(arr+i)=='k')
            cout<<"-.-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='L'||*(arr+i)=='l')
            cout<<".-..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='M'||*(arr+i)=='m')
            cout<<"--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='N'||*(arr+i)=='n')
            cout<<"-.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='O'||*(arr+i)=='o')
            cout<<"---";
            if(*(arr+i)=='P'||*(arr+i)=='p')
            cout<<".--.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='Q'||*(arr+i)=='q')
            cout<<"--.-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='R'||*(arr+i)=='r')
            cout<<".-.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='S'||*(arr+i)=='s')
            cout<<"...";
            if(*(arr+i)=='T'||*(arr+i)=='t')
            cout<<"-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='U'||*(arr+i)=='u')
            cout<<"..-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='V'||*(arr+i)=='v')
            cout<<"...-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='W'||*(arr+i)=='w')
            cout<<".--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='X'||*(arr+i)=='x')
            cout<<"-..-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='Y'||*(arr+i)=='y')
            cout<<"-.--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='Z'||*(arr+i)=='z')
            cout<<"--..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='0')
            cout<<"-----";
            if(*(arr+i)=='1')
            cout<<".----";
            if(*(arr+i)=='2')
            cout<<"..---";
            if(*(arr+i)=='3')
            cout<<"...--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='4')
            cout<<"....-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='5')
            cout<<".....";
            if(*(arr+i)=='6')
            cout<<"-....";
            if(*(arr+i)=='7')
            cout<<"--...";
            if(*(arr+i)=='8')
            cout<<"---..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='9')
            cout<<"----.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='.')
            cout<<".-.-.-";
            if(*(arr+i)==',')
            cout<<"--..--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='?')
            cout<<"..--..";
            if(*(arr+i)=='\'')
            cout<<".---.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='!')
            cout<<"-.-.--";
            if(*(arr+i)=='/')
            cout<<"-.--.";
            if(*(arr+i)=='(')
            cout<<"-.--.";
            if(*(arr+i)==')')
            cout<<"-.--.-";
            if(*(arr+i)=='&')
            cout<<".-...";
            /*if(*(arr+i)!='A'||*(arr+i)!='a'||*(arr+i)!='B'||*(arr+i)!='b'||*(arr+i)!='C'||*(arr+i)!='c'||*(arr+i)!='D'||*(arr+i)!='d'||*(arr+i)!='E'||*(arr+i)!='e'||*(arr+i)!='F'||*(arr+i)!='f'||*(arr+i)!='G'||*(arr+i)!='g'||*(arr+i)!='H'||*(arr+i)!='h'||*(arr+i)!='I'||*(arr+i)!='i'||*(arr+i)!='J'||*(arr+i)!='j'||*(arr+i)!='K'||*(arr+i)!='k'||*(arr+i)!='L'||*(arr+i)!='l'||*(arr+i)!='M'||*(arr+i)!='m'||*(arr+i)!='N'||*(arr+i)!='n'||*(arr+i)!='O'||*(arr+i)!='o'||*(arr+i)!='P'||*(arr+i)!='p'||*(arr+i)!='Q'||*(arr+i)!='q'||*(arr+i)!='R'||*(arr+i)!='S'||*(arr+i)!='s'||*(arr+i)!='T'||*(arr+i)!='t'||*(arr+i)!='U'||*(arr+i)!='u'||*(arr+i)!='V'||*(arr+i)!='v'||*(arr+i)!='W'||*(arr+i)!='w'||*(arr+i)!='X'||*(arr+i)!='x'||*(arr+i)!='Y'||*(arr+i)!='y'||*(arr+i)!='Z'||*(arr+i)!='z'||*(arr+i)!='0'||*(arr+i)!='1'||*(arr+i)!='2'||*(arr+i)!='3'||*(arr+i)!='4'||*(arr+i)!='5'||*(arr+i)!='6'||*(arr+i)!='7'||*(arr+i)!='8'||*(arr+i)!='9'||*(arr+i)!='.'||*(arr+i)!=','||*(arr+i)!='?'||*(arr+i)!='\''||*(arr+i)!='!'||*(arr+i)!='/'||*(arr+i)!='('||*(arr+i)!=')'||*(arr+i)!='&')
            cout<<" ";
            */
            if(arr[i] == ' ')
                cout<<" ";
        }
break;


    }


}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i need to submit this code in some time and i dont have time to learn how to work a debugger, please if you could check it for me i would greatful

Comment: this is what it says [Inferior 1 (process 61) exited normally] in gdb and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: We do not debug other people's programs here, unfortunately. Stackoverflow is not a debugging site. We only answer ***specific*** questions on programming topics. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ programmer. C++ is just too complicated, and it's not possible to write C++ code of any non-trivial length without using a debugger. And you only need to learn how to use a debugger just once. Once you know how to use it, you can find and fix all problems in your own code, without asking anyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

An expression in a condition in your loop

```
for(int i=0; *(arr+i)<=length; i++) //WE TAKE i<=length BECAUSE THE STRLEN FUNCTION DOESNT COUNT \0
```

`*(arr+i)` means a value of the array `arr` at offset `i`, or simply `arr[i]` that is easier on the eyes.

Now, why does `arr[i]` must be less than or equal to `length`?

Also your comment on that line makes no sense. Although the terminating `0` is not counted, you don't need to convert it to Morse code. In fact, there is no encoding for `\0`. So the condition should be `< length`.

Oh, and you don't need to invent a function for getting the length of the string, there are couple of them available.

On the other hand, you don't even need to know the length of your string, just go until you see that `\0`.

Comment: ok i changed what you said, eventhough they  were the requirement that i needed to follow. However the changes still dont solve the segmentation core dump issue in my code

Comment: @ColsonBaker I don’t see what you have changed…

Answer (score 0):

instead of using pointer `ptr` use the name of the array